# Strange Behavior When Reading From a File in C

Tags: c

I am trying to read the file "someNumbers" with this content (separator between numbers is a tab "\t"):

```
-711519 -69537  691937  -363942 746815  -761877 885027  759668  -483649 640827  201850  -510648
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int strangeArray[4];
    long currentSeek = 0;
    for (n=0;n<4;n++ )
    {
        printf("%d %s\n" , n, "For!");
        currentSeek  = currentSeek + (22 * n);
        FILE *fb = fopen("someNumbers.txt","r");
        fseek(fb, currentSeek, SEEK_SET);
        if( n > 0 && n < 3){
            char dummy[1];
            fscanf(fb, "%*[^\t]%1s", dummy);
            if(n==0)  printf("%d %s\n" , n , "WHY IS THIS PRINTED!!!!");
        }

        strangeArray[0] = 1; // When this line removed .. the code works fine!
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, instead of reading the file, the loop is reset and (n) value is set to 0.

Can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What **is** the problem?

Comment: Why do you keep opening the same file in a loop?

Comment: `char dummy[1];` --> `char dummy[2];`

Comment: You never `fclose(fb)`.  You will quickly run out of `FILE*` handles. But you do not check if `fopen()` fails...

Comment: please do not down-vote the question, I know there should be fclose and all these stuff, the question is very specific, please let your answers also be specific.

@BLUEPIXY thanks thats was all i needed.

Comment: Not understanding what this code do, does not automatically means down-voting the question. this is a snap that only illustrate the problem. that does not have error handling or any best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you think

```
fscanf(fb, "%*[^\t]%1s", dummy);
```

is going to store the string it reads?
The `dummy` is an array of a single char, so the terminating NUL is written past the array, invoking **undefined behavior**.

And why do you use `fscanf`, `fopen` and `fseek` without checking their return values? That's reason enough Stackoverflow should reject your question automatically...

If you need to read some white-space separated integers, why not use a loop that simply does

```
 int retval = fscanf (fb, " %d", &number);
 if (retval == 1) {
          ...got a number...
 } else if (retval == EOF) {
          ...we're done...
 } else {
          ...error...
 }
```

until it hits `EOF`?

Comment: I have a very long code, that i don't want to share, can you provide a solution ?

Comment: I have made the dummy [2] , and it solved the problem, thanks !!

Comment: @العمريللحلولالبرمجية You're not done. Having the `fopen` in the loop you will quickly run into another segfault if there are more than a few hundred numbers in the file. Check **all return values**, mate.

Comment: @العمريللحلولالبرمجية: in other words, you forget to `fclose(fb)`.

Comment: I am very sure that asking stupied qustions on stackoverflow is OK, nevertheless on my orginal code, i did all checking and error handling, i was just simplifying the code to the least amount, while keeping the strange behavior. Thanks for your answer it was helpful.